# Insert from select with sequence and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to insert some data into table `tableA`, but I have to use `group by` and `my_sequence.nextval`. It is impossible to use both in the same statment, is exists any workaround ?

For example:

```
insert into tableA (
  taba_id,
  taba_sum,
  taba_date
) select 
  tabb_sequence.nextval,
  sum(tabb_value),
  tabb_date
  from 
  tableB group by (tabb_date);
```

After execute this statment, I got:

```
ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
```

According oracle documentation,I should get this error. 
How to deal with sequence and group by caluses in one statment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is because your sequence is not aggregated, therefore you have this error. Try this way:

```
insert into tableA (
  taba_id,
  taba_date,
  taba_sum
) 
 select tabb_sequence.nextval,
        tabb_date,
        stv
   from (select tabb_date,
                sum(tabb_value) stv,
           from tableB 
          group by tabb_date) a;
```